# How to optimize C for loop for font rendering on oled display

Tags: c, optimization

I need to optimize this function: Any strange way to optimize the for loop? (early break i think can't be possible)

```
void SeeedGrayOLED::putChar(unsigned char C)
{
if(C < 32 || C > 127) //Ignore non-printable ASCII characters. This can be modified for multilingual font.
{
    C=' '; //Space
}   

uint8_t k,offset = 0;
char bit1,bit2,c = 0;

for(char i=0;i<16;i++)
{
    for(char j=0;j<32;j+=2)
    {

        if(i>8){
            k=i-8;
            offset = 1;
        }else{
            k=i;
        }

        // Character is constructed two pixel at a time using vertical mode from the default 8x8 font
        c=0x00;
        bit1=(pgm_read_byte(&hallfetica_normal[C-32][j+offset]) >> (8-k))  & 0x01;  
        bit2=(pgm_read_byte(&hallfetica_normal[C-32][j+offset]) >> ((8-k)-1)) & 0x01;
       // Each bit is changed to a nibble
        c|=(bit1)?grayH:0x00;
        c|=(bit2)?grayL:0x00;
        sendData(c);
    }
}

}
```

I've got a font in the array hallfetica_normal, is an array of array of uint8_t, that maybe compressed or something like that?

This code run on a arduino, ad i've to run a countdown from 500 to 0 with one unit down every 10/20ms.

**EDIT**

This is the new code after yours indication, thanks all:
I'm looking to organise the font differently to permit less call to pgm_read_byte.. (something like changing the orientation... i wonder)

```
void SeeedGrayOLED::putChar(unsigned char C)
{
if(C < 32 || C > 127) //Ignore non-printable ASCII characters. This can be modified for multilingual font.
{
    C=' '; //Space
}   

char c,byte = 0x00;
unsigned char nibble_lookup[] = { 0, grayL, grayH, grayH | grayL };

for(int ii=0;ii<2;ii++){
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<32;j+=2)
        {
            byte = pgm_read_byte(&hallfetica_normal[C-32][j+ii]);
            c = nibble_lookup[(byte >> (8-i)) & 3];
            sendData(c);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: FYI, this type of question is best suited for [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No need to set `c` to zero; initialize it with your first OR. Also, no need to move a `0` or `1` into `c`. You can test the bits immediately, using `& (1<<j)`. Probably many more optimizations like this.

Comment: What's in sendData? Is it possible to send data in blocks instead of one byte at a time?

Answer (score 4):

Well, you seem to be reading the same byte twice in a row unnecessarily via `pgm_read_byte(&hallfetica_normal[C-32][j+offset])`. You could load that once into a local variable.

Additionally, you could avoid the `if(i>8){` check per iteration by breaking up the code into two loops; one where `i` goes from 0 to 8 and another where it goes from 9 to 15. (Although I suspect you really intended `>=` here, making the loop boundaries 0-7 then 8-15.) That also means things like `offset` become constant values, which will help.

Comment: I've changed removing the 2 two call of pgm_read_byte, and i've replaced with one, removed the assignment to the temporary variales that fit the bits. Then i've added a for loop from 0 to 2 that contain the other two loops. now it's not very more fast than before, i'm going to try the solution shown by indiv, and next try to optimize the font array. Thank you, i'll upate soon.

Comment: You should post your new code as well to help us see if it is as expected.

Answer (score 2):

In an effort to make the inner loop as fast as possible, I'd try to get rid of all branching with a lookup table and see whether that helped.

First, I'd define the lookup table outside the loop:

```
/* outside the loop */
unsigned char h_lookup[] = { 0, grayH };
unsigned char l_lookup[] = { 0, grayL };
```

Then inside the loop, since you're testing the least-significant bit, you can use that as an index into the lookup table.  If it's clear, then the lookup index will be 0.  If it's set, then the lookup index will be 1:

```
/* inside the loop */
byte = pgm_read_byte(&hallfetica_normal[C-32][j+offset]);
c = h_lookup[((byte >> (8-k)) & 0x01)] |
    l_lookup[((byte >> (8-k-1)) & 0x01)]
sendData(c);
```

Since you're masking and testing 2 adjacent bits, `8-k` and `8-k-1`, you could list all 4 possibilities in a single lookup table:

```
/* Outside loop */
unsigned char nibble_lookup[] = { 0, grayL, grayH, grayH | grayL };
```

And then the lookup becomes dramatically simplified.

```
/* loop */
byte = pgm_read_byte(&hallfetica_normal[C-32][j+offset]);
c = nibble_lookup[(byte >> (8-k)) & 3];
sendData(c);
```

The other answer has addressed what to do about the branches in the top part of your inner loop.